# rails route error when include module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

when I include module in controller, the routing is not work, report 404 not found error, below is my code,  very sample

*ruby: 2.0, rails: 4.2.3*

**routes.rb**

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', via: :all
```

**common.rb**

```
module Common
  class A; end
end
```

**test_controller.rb**

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  include Common  # when I delete this line , this route '/test/hello' works as expected,
                  # otherwise rails reports 404 not found

  def hello
    render :json => {msg: 'hello'}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`module/class` name should start with capital letter `Common`

```
module Common
  class A; end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is a typo mistake, I've already corrected it

Comment: If you find the answer is useful, please accept @Codisan